# Manufacturer -> Model chained select, data pulled from JSON. How to tie in to existing refreshSelect function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I know this question is long, I apologize. There's a lot going on in this form, and I'm getting confused.

Background: I have a form that allows me to add assets to a database using manufacturer, model, supplier, etc. Some fields in the form have a button beside the field that allows new data to be added to the database via a modal window with its own form. After successful modal form submission is complete, the modal window closes, the select element is "refreshed", and it pulls in and selects the newly added data in the select element of the parent form.

Here is the code that I cobbled together to get the above functionality working:

Processes modal form submission:

```
$(document).ready(function () //function to process modal form via ajax
{
    $('.modal-submit').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); //prevent default form submit action

        var data = $(this).serialize();
        var type = $(this).find('input[name="type"]').val() //get value of hidden input
        var url = $(this).attr('action'); //get action from form
        var modal = $(this).closest('.modal');
        var modalInput = $(this).find('.form-row input'); //get input from form
        var modalId = $(this).closest('.modal').attr('id');

        $.ajax({
            url:url,
            method:'POST',
            data:data,
            success:function(response){
                console.log(data);
                refreshData(newId = response.id, modalId); //set newId to the id of the newly inserted item, get modalId
                modal.modal('hide'); //hide modal after successful form submit
                $(modalInput).val(''); //clear input values after successful form submit
            },
            error:function(response){
                console.log(data);
                $.each(response.responseJSON.error, function (i, error) {
                    $('#'+ i).parent('.input-group').addClass('has-error').siblings('.backend-error').html(error[0]);
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Functions that populate my select elements:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  refreshData();
});

function refreshData(newId, modalId) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/json/collection.json',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        if(modalId){
            switch(modalId){
                case "supplierModal":
                    refreshSelect('inputSupplier', data.suppliers, newId);
                    break;
                case "manufacturerModal":
                    refreshSelect('inputManufacturer', data.manufacturers, newId);
                    refreshSelect('inputManufacturerModel', data.manufacturers, newId); //modal window select
                    break;
                case "statusModal":
                    refreshSelect('inputStatus', data.status, newId);
                    break;
                case "categoryModal":
                    refreshSelect('inputCategory', data.categories, newId);
                    break;
            }
        }else{
            refreshSelect('inputSupplier', data.suppliers);
            refreshSelect('inputManufacturer', data.manufacturers);
            refreshSelect('inputStatus', data.status);
            refreshSelect('inputCategory', data.categories);
            refreshSelect('inputManufacturerModel', data.manufacturers); //refresh modal window select element
        }
    }
  });
}

function refreshSelect(name, data, newId) {
    // Select by id
    let $elem = $('#' + name);
    // Get current value
    let oldValue = $elem.val();
    // Get option with value 0, which is the first element
    let emptyOption = $elem.children('option').first();
    // Empty the element and add the option. We are back to initial state
    $elem.html(emptyOption);
    // Append elements retrieved from backend
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        if(oldValue === key || newId === key){
            $elem.append('<option value="' + key + '" selected="selected">' + value + '</option>');
        }else{
            $elem.append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>');
        }
    });
    if(newId){
      $elem.val(newId);
    }else{
      $elem.val(oldValue);
    }
}
```

Format of data:

```
{"suppliers":{"1":"Amazon","2":"Lenovo"},"manufacturers":{"1":"Apple"},"categories":{"4":"Desktop","3":"Laptop","2":"Tablet"},"status":{"3":"Damaged","2":"Deployed","4":"Destroyed","1":"Ready to Deploy"}}
```

All of the above is working.

**Current behavior of my manufacturer -> model chained select:**

In the main form that contains all my form fields, I have a chained select for manufacturer -> model. When a manufacturer has at least 1 linked model, it will populate the model select with the models from the database via JSON for the selected manufacturer.

**What I'm trying to accomplish:**

I'm trying to make it so that when a new model is added via a database insert from my modal window, the model select element will update with the new model appended to the existing select element and mark it as selected. I can't find a way to "tie in" to my "refreshData" function because the data is coming from a different JSON response.

Here is the code for my manufacturer -> model chained select:

```
$(document).ready(function () // manufacturer -> model dependent select
{
    $("#inputModelNoNew").keyup(function () { //transform model # input in modal window to uppercase
        $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());  
    });

    var inputManufacturer = 'select[name="inputManufacturer"]'; //manufacturer select element in parent form
    var inputModel = 'select[name="inputModel"]'; //model select element in parent form
    var inputManufacturerModel = 'select[name="inputManufacturerModel"]'; //manufacturer select element in modal window
    var modalInput = $(this).find('.form-row input'); //get input value from modal window form
    /* ADDED */ var modalId = $(this).closest('.modal').attr('id');

    $(inputManufacturer).on('change',function(){ //on manufacturer select change
        $(inputModel).prop('disabled', false); //enable model select element in form
        $(inputManufacturerModel).prop('disabled', false); //enable model select in modal
        var man_ID = $(this).val(); //assign value of select to man_ID

        if(man_ID > 0) //if manufacturer select value is > default value of 0, look for children via ajax call
        {
            $(inputManufacturerModel).val(man_ID).attr('readonly', true); //set modal manufacturer select to disabled and pass the value
            $.ajax({
                url : 'add/' + man_ID,
                type : 'GET',
                dataType : 'json',
                success:function(data){
                    if( data.models.length === 0 ){ //if no children are returned from ajax call
                        $(inputModel).prop('disabled', true).html('<option value="0">No models for this manufacturer. Add model &#11157;</option>');
                    }else{
                        $(inputModel).empty(); //clear values from model select element
                        $.each(data.models, function(key, value){
                            $(inputModel).append('<option value="'+ key +'" >'+ value +'</option>');
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }else{ //display default values
            $(inputModel).html('<option value="0">Select model...</option>').prop('disabled', true); //default value of model select when no manufacturer selected
        }
    });
});
```

Format of models data:

```
{"models":{"1":"MW742LL/A - iPad 7th Generation WiFi 32GB","2":"MD510LL/A - iPad 4th Generation WiFi 32GB"}}
```

Relevant form html:

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 mb-3 mb-sm-4 mb-md-4">
        <label for="inputManufacturer">Manufacturer *</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <select name="inputManufacturer" id="inputManufacturer" class="form-control" required="required" onclick="refreshData()">
                <option value="0">Select manufacturer...</option>
            </select>
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#manufacturerModal"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> New</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 mb-3 mb-sm-4 mb-md-4">
        <label for="inputModel">Model *</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <select name="inputModel" id="inputModel" class="form-control" disabled>
                <option value="0">Select model...</option>
            </select>
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modelModal"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> New</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Relevant modal html to add models for a specific manufacturer:

```
<!-- Add New Model Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modelModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modelModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="modelModalLabel">Add new asset model</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <form method="post" class="modal-submit" autocomplete="off" action="{{ action('AddAssetController@addDescriptor', ['type' => 'model']) }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="type" value="model">
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                        <label for="inputManufacturerModel">Manufacturer *</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <select name="inputManufacturerModel" id="inputManufacturerModel" class="form-control" required="required" onclick="refreshData()">
                                <option value="0">Select manufacturer...</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                        <label for="inputModelNew">New model name *</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" name="inputModelNew" id="inputModelNew" class="form-control" placeholder="Example: iPad 7th Generation WiFi 32GB" required="required">
                        </div>
                        <div class="backend-error"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                        <label for="inputModelNoNew">New model # *</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" name="inputModelNoNew" id="inputModelNoNew" class="form-control" placeholder="Example: MW742LL/A" required="required">
                        </div>
                        <div class="backend-error"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="float-right">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- / Add New Model Modal -->
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Revised code for manufacturer -> model chain select:

```
$(document).ready(function () // manufacturer -> model dependent select
{
    $("#inputModelNoNew").keyup(function () { //transform model # input in modal window to uppercase
        $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());  
    });

    var inputManufacturer = 'select[name="inputManufacturer"]'; //manufacturer select element in parent form
    var inputModel = 'select[name="inputModel"]'; //model select element in parent form
    var inputManufacturerModel = 'select[name="inputManufacturerModel"]'; //manufacturer select element in modal window
    var modalInput = $(this).find('.form-row input'); //get input value from modal window form

    $(inputManufacturer).on('change',function(){ //on manufacturer select change
        $(inputModel).prop('disabled', false); //enable model select element in form
        $(inputManufacturerModel).prop('disabled', false); //enable model select in modal
        var man_ID = $(this).val(); //assign value of select to man_ID

        if(man_ID > 0) //if manufacturer select value is > default value of 0, look for children via ajax call
        {
            $(inputManufacturerModel).val(man_ID).attr('readonly', true); //set modal manufacturer select to disabled and pass the value
            $.ajax({
                url : 'add/' + man_ID,
                type : 'GET',
                dataType : 'json',
                success:function(data){
                    if( data.models.length === 0 ){ //if no children are returned from ajax call
                        $(inputModel).prop('disabled', true).html('<option value="0">No models for this manufacturer. Add model &#11157;</option>');
                    }else{
                        $(inputModel).empty(); //clear values from model select element
                        refreshData();
                    }
                }
            });
        }else{ //display default values
            $(inputModel).html('<option value="0">Select model...</option>').prop('disabled', true); //default value of model select when no manufacturer selected
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @msg Hey! Good to see you again. :) Right now, as it is, adding a new model to the db will close the modal window and do nothing. You have to refresh the page before seeing the model added to the select. I did try calling '''refreshSelect``` after the data was submitted, and it kind of worked, but there was no way to mark the new model as selected. The chain select is parsing JSON from a different url, so I'm thinking this may not be possible. The regular ```refreshSelect``` pulls from ```/json/collection.json``` and the chained select performs a GET request on a totally different url.

Comment: You're correct. I got the function names switched. Using ```refreshSelect```, it did return the results I was looking for, but I couldn't get it to work completely. When the model select was loaded after adding a new one via the modal window, I couldn't figure out how to make it selected in the parent form by default and it would clear the select element before loading in the content, but there was a weird whitespace issue or a blank line. If there are better ways to accomplish this, I'd love some pointers.

Comment: Yeah that should be enough. Here's what a response will look like when I select Apple from the manufacturer select: ```{"models":{"1":"MW742LL\/A - iPad 7th Generation WiFi 32GB","2":"MD510LL\/A - iPad 4th Generation WiFi 32GB"}}``` How do I get the id of each model from this response? I was looping through them with ```$(inputModel).append('<option value="'+ key +'" >'+ value +'</option>');```

Comment: Ok, update. I've got it working mostly. I added the models data to the collection.json along with suppliers, manufacturers, etc.When I add a new model, it correctly adds it to the db and is properly selected once the modal closes. However, I'm back to my original problem. When I initially load the parent form and then select a manufacturer, it's loading the models for the manufacturer, but there's a weird space that I can't seem to figure out where it's coming from. Any ideas? See gif: [Odd whitespace](https://imgur.com/a/rQar2jz)

Comment: I added my revised code for the manufacturer->model chain select at the bottom of my original question at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a two parter. The first concern is to get the model list for the manufacturer when it changes.

```
$(inputManufacturer).on('change', function() { //on manufacturer select change
  $(inputModel).prop('disabled', false); //enable model select element in form
  $(inputManufacturerModel).prop('disabled', false); //enable model select in modal
  var man_ID = $(this).val(); //assign value of select to man_ID

  if (man_ID > 0) //if manufacturer select value is > default value of 0, look for children via ajax call
  {
    $(inputManufacturerModel).val(man_ID).attr('readonly', true); //set modal manufacturer select to disabled and pass the value
    $.ajax({
      url: 'add/' + man_ID,
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        // This is a bit of a cheat, but it makes easier to set the 'legend' of the field
        //   since we don't have to deal with the first value changing on us and 
        //   that's what refreshSelect will keep
        refreshSelect('inputModel', data.models);

        // Calling    $(inputModel).empty();    in your original code removed the first element,
        //   producing a blank value.
        // No need to call    refreshData(); since no data is changing
        if (data.models.length === 0) {
          $(inputModel).prop('disabled', true);
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

The second is to refresh the model list after adding the new item. There are two options, you could:

1. Just return the `id` and `name` of the new element from your controller and insert it manually (or only the `id`, even, and get the name from the form itself).
2. Send the `id` along the whole model list in the response, something like `{ newid: "7", models: { ... }}`.

Since the part that deals with the submission is missing, I'll only give you the basic idea (for the second option):

```
$('#modelModal form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $modal = $(this).closest('.modal');
  $.ajax({
    // Setup
    success: function(data) {
      // Whatever you are doing now...

      let newId = data.new; // Get the new id from the response to select it
      refreshSelect('inputModel', data.models, newId);
      // In case this is the first model for this manufacturer
      $('#inputModel').prop('disabled', false);
      $modal.close();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Just getting back to this. I really appreciate your help. I edited the code for the manufacturer select so it no longer shows the blank line. However, I can't get option 2 for the model list to work. I can do option 1. I've edited my code to send the following response when adding a new model to the db: ```{success: true, man_id: "2", model_name: "New Model Name", id: "8"}```. "man_id" is the id of the manufacturer that the model belongs to, "model_name" is the new model's name, and the id is the id of the new model. Can you elaborate on how to insert it manually in the model select?

Comment: @DerekM. Do you really need `man_id`? Isn't already selected? I thought the modal was for the *specific* manufacturer. Otherwise you might need more legwork, since you'll have to update both the manufacturer **and** model. But changing the manufacturer will refresh the model list, and the new model should already be there, so it'd just be a matter of selecting the value? To append an element, call `.append()` just like you were doing before, no looping, and use `id` and `name` in place of `key` and `value`.

Comment: You're correct, didn't need it. Here's what I ended up doing: After db insertion, I included the id, model name, and model number in the response, I took that info and did a call to ```refreshModels()``` right under ```refreshData()```. ```refreshModels``` is just a function that appends a new option tag on the end with the data that is passed to it. Thank you so much for your help with this. I've learned a lot.